# Python/Pandas – Como comparar se conteúdo de coluna do data frame, no formato date, é igual a outra coluna de data mais ou menos 1 dia?

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho um data frame com duas colunas no formato data e preciso comparar se uma delas está entre o intervalo de um dia a mais ou a menos que outra coluna.
Por exemplo:
Coluna A = 2015-03-02
Coluna B = 2015-03-01
Comparação:
If Coluna A == Coluna B:
    Return ‘Coluna A dentro do intervalo’
Elif (Coluna B - 1) == Coluna A:
    Return ‘Coluna dentro do intervalo’
Elif (Coluna B + 1) == Coluna A:
    Return ‘Coluna A dentro do intervalo’
Else:
    Return ‘Coluna A FORA do intervalo aceito’

Answer (score 3):

Olá, só uma sugestão, para escrever códigos utilize a ferramenta do StackOverflow própria para isso. Fica no ícone `{}` do editor de texto.

Para fazer isso, você pode usar o método `pd.to_datetime().day` e pedir o dia diretamente.

Estou considerando que você já está usando o `pandas` para manipular o DataFrame e que coluna_A e coluna_B só são valores das células do DataFrame.

```
coluna_A = '2015-03-02' 
coluna_B = '2015-03-01'
A = coluna_A.to_datetime().day
B = coluna_B.to_datetime().day

def comparacao( A , B):
    if (A <= B+1 and A >= B-1): 
        return 'Coluna A dentro do intervalo' 
    else: 
        return 'Coluna A FORA do intervalo aceito'

comparacao(A,B)
```